# Problem to update a date_select field from a tableselect radio button via ajax callback. Other fields are well updated

Tags: ajax, datetime, forms

Here is the corresponding code and a print screen of what happens when clicking a radio button (you can see it works well for type 'select' and 'textarea')
I use Drupal core 7.31 and Date Date 7.x-2.8 (same problem with Date 7.x-2.x-dev).

Thanks in advance !

```
/**
 * Sample UI to update a record.
 */
function avf_crises_form_update($form, &$form_state) {
  $entries = avf_crises_entry_load();
  $keyed_entries = array();
  if (empty($entries)) {
    $form['no_values'] = array(
      '#value' => t("No entry founded."),
    );
    return $form;
  }
  foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $options[$entry->pid] = t("@pid: @cdate @cduration @cintensity @ctreatment @ccomment @uid",
      array(
        '@pid'            => $entry->pid,
        '@cdate'          => $entry->cdate,
        '@ctime'          => $entry->ctime,
        '@cduration'      => $entry->cduration,
        '@cintensity'     => $entry->cintensity,
        '@ctreatment'     => $entry->ctreatment,
        '@ccomment'       => $entry->ccomment,
        '@uid'            => $entry->uid,
        )
      );
  $xdate = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($entry->cdate));
  $xtime = date('H:i', strtotime($entry->ctime));
  $xduration = date('H:i', strtotime($entry->cduration));
  $xcomment = br2nl($entry->ccomment);

    $rows[$entry->pid] = array(
      $xdate,
      $xtime,
      $entry->cintensity,
      $xduration,
      $entry->ctreatment,
      $entry->ccomment,
    );

    $keyed_entries[$entry->pid] = $entry;
  }
  $header = array(
    array('data' => t('Date'), 'field' => 'cdate', 'sort' => 'DESC'),
    array('data' => t('Time'), 'field' => 'ctime'),
    array('data' => t('Intensity'), 'field' => 'cintensity'),
    array('data' => t('Duration'), 'field' => 'cduration'),
    array('data' => t('Treatment'), 'field' => 'ctreatment'),
    array('data' => t('Comments'), 'field' => 'ccomment'),
  );
  $default_entry = $entries[0];

  $form_state['entries'] = $keyed_entries;

  $form['upd'] = array(
    '#type'  => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Choose a crisis'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="updateform">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  $form['upd']['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#title' => t('Table'),
      '#options' => $rows,
      '#multiple' => FALSE,
    '#js_select' => FALSE,
    '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'updateform',
      'callback' => 'avf_crises_form_update_callback',
    ),
  );
  $form['upd']['cdate'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_select',
        '#date_format' => 'd-M-Y',
    '#title' => t('Date'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['upd']['ctime'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_select',
        '#date_format' => 'h:i',
    '#title' => t('Time'),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $dropdown_array = array(1 => '1', 2 => '2', 3 => '3', 4 => '4', 5 => '5', 6 => '6', 7 => '7', 8 => '8', 9 => '9', 10 => '10');
    $form['upd']['cintensity'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $dropdown_array,
    '#title' => t('Intensity'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['upd']['cduration'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_select',
        '#date_format' => 'h:i',
        '#title' => t('Duration'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $dropdown_array = array('None' => 'None', 'Imitrex full' => 'Imitrex full', 'Imitrex half' => 'Imitrex half', 'Imitrex one third' => 'Imitrex one third', 'Oxygen 15 lmin' => 'Oxygen 15 lmin', 'Oxygen 12 lmin' => 'Oxygen 12 lmin', 'Oxygen 9 lmin' => 'Oxygen 9 lmin', 'Other' => 'Other');
  $form['upd']['ctreatment'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $dropdown_array,
    '#title' => t('Treatment'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['upd']['ccomment'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Comments'),
    '#rows' => 3,
    '#required' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['upd']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Update'),
  );
  return $form;
}

/**
 * AJAX callback handler for the pid select.
 * When the pid changes, populates the defaults from the database in the form.
 */
function avf_crises_form_update_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $entry = $form_state['entries'][$form_state['values']['table']];
  foreach (array('cdate', 'ctime', 'cintensity', 'cduration', 'ctreatment', 'ccomment') as $item) {
    $form['upd'][$item]['#value'] = $entry->$item;
  }
  $form['upd']['ccomment']['#value'] = br2nl($entry->ccomment);
  return $form;
}
```

[image: Result after selection]

Comment: In quick : Is a field of type "date_select" supports updates via AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

1) date must be set as array

2) strval(intval => prevent leading zero problem (if leading zero it do not work, except for minute and second ... why, I don't know ...)

```
function avf_crises_form_update_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $entry = $form_state['entries'][$form_state['values']['table']];
  foreach (array('cdate', 'ctime', 'cintensity', 'cduration', 'ctreatment', 'ccomment') as $item) {
    $form['upd'][$item]['#value'] = $entry->$item;
  }
  $form['upd']['ccomment']['#value'] = br2nl($entry->ccomment);

  // Set dates array
  list($zdate, $ztime) = explode(' ', $form['upd']['adate']['#value']);
  list($zyear, $zmonth, $zday) = explode('-', $zdate);
  list($zhour, $zminute, $zsecond) = explode(':', $ztime);

  $form['upd']['cdate']['year']['#value'] = strval(intval($zyear));
  $form['upd']['cdate']['month']['#value'] = strval(intval($zmonth));
  $form['upd']['cdate']['day']['#value'] = strval(intval($zday));
  $form['upd']['cdate']['hour']['#value'] = strval(intval($zhour));
  $form['upd']['cdate']['minute']['#value'] = $zminute;
  $form['upd']['cdate']['second']['#value'] = $zsecond;

  return $form;
}
```